# Check website with through multiple IP address, without changing DNS

Tags: linux, monitoring, website

I want to automate my website uptime and availability testing. i have sucuri proxy in place, after that there is a load balancer, and then there are application servers behind load balancer. is there any way i can automate the checking of my website to resolve to Sucuri proxy IP (1st) check its status,then check for pointing IP to LB, test it, and then point it to other application servers behind LB? 
I just want to do it to make sure that when disaster comes, then which portion of website is down, so i get instant notification of the failure at specific level.

Is it possible by adding website IP and url to hosts file?(through a bash script, then change hosts file accordingly for each test)? or there is any other way out for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `curl` for testing, check `--resolve` and `-H` i.e. `--header`.

This would imitate your `hosts`-file solution:

```
curl --resolve example.com:443:192.0.2.1 https://example.com:443/
```

While this replaces the `Host:` header:

```
curl -H "Host: example.com" https://appserver.example.com/
```

Those two can also be combined, if better for some parts of your testing.